# What does this declare?

Tags: java, class

```
public class Neat {

    public Neat asdf;
}
```

does this make an object of the class Neat? I'm currently trying to learn Linked Lists, if that helps.

I've no idea how to Google this, sorry.

Comment: It declares a class that has a member variable of the same type of the class defined. I would consider googling recursion.

Comment: Maybe asdf points to the parent/child of the current Neat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This creates a class named`Neat` that declares a member variable named `asdf` of type `Neat`. The member variable `asdf` is a reference to `null`.

This code, as is, does not create an instance of an object `Neat`

Comment: So when you declare a variable with the same name as the class, it becomes a "point-able" reference? As opposed to a data of some type like String or int?

Comment: You could declare `public String string;` This would create member variable named string of type `String`. Since string is an `Object` (a reference type) it is also a reference to null. Here is a list of defaults for member (or instance) variables http://web.archive.org/web/20120111040944/http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#96595

Comment: Woah thanks! Just to clarify for me, `public String string;` is a reference that starts as null, but can point to a string, `public Neat something;` is a reference also starts as null, but can point to.....anything?

Comment: It can reference null or some String e.g. string = "my string"; It may also start as a reference to a string e.g. public String string = "my string"

Comment: i am referring to `string`

Answer (score 0):

This declare a field of type `Neat`. So the Neat object will have a children `Neat` field.

```
 Neat n = new Neat();
 n.asdf = new Neat();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a class with a member variable that is of the same type as the class. This is perfectly legal in this case, however it can be dangerous. For example, if you change your code to merely instantiate the variable

```
public Neat asdf = new Neat();
```

Then create a `Neat` elsewhere, your program will crash with a `StackOverflowError` because each instance creates a new instance, which creates a new instance, and so on. As it stands, your program creates a reference variable, but not an instance, so no further instances are created.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Neat {

public Neat asdf; //Focus here

public static void main(String...string){
    Neat n = new Neat();
}
}
```

No,It does not create an object, its is just a variable having potential to have object of Neat class
but

```
public class Neat {

public Neat asdf = new Neat(); //Focus here

public static void main(String...string){
    Neat n = new Neat();
}
}
```

It will make as many object of Neat and eventually result in StackOverFlow...